# Spresense SDKで提供されているadc_monitorのサンプルプログラムについて

Tags: spresense

Spresenseのメインボードと拡張ボードを組み合わせて使用しております。
HPADCを使用した場合の電圧値への変換式を教えてください。
各入力ゲイン(-6,0,6,12,14)に対しての変換式をお願いします。
[image: HPで公開されている特性グラフ：この変換式をお願いします。]

Answer (score 0):

ADC値が符号付き16bit(signed short)の値となって取得される(それをvalとする)。
Vref電圧が5.0Vで、それを27KΩと10KΩで抵抗分圧して1.4Vを入力している。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_ad変換器の使用方法](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_ad%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E5%99%A8%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)
デシベルとゲインの関係は以下のように表される。
y [dB]＝20 * log10(N) [倍]
-6dB->1/2倍, 0dB->1倍, 6dB->2倍, 12dB->4倍, 14dB->6倍

電圧Vppに対して取得される電圧への換算式は次のようになると思います。

V=(Vpp/10^(dB/20)*(val+32768)/65536 + (1.4-Vpp/10^(dB/20))/2) * (27+10)/10

理想的には、Vpp=0.7V、-6dB設定で0~5V(=Vref)が-32768~32767になることですが、
抵抗誤差や配線抵抗、入力電圧の精度などによりズレがあります。
ズレるのは元々容量結合を意図したADCのように見えるのでそれもあるかと思います。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_より微小な信号をad変換する場合](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E5%BE%AE%E5%B0%8F%E3%81%AA%E4%BF%A1%E5%8F%B7%E3%82%92ad%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)

参考にArduino環境でどうしているのかをみてみると、
上限/下限値をもとにリニアにmap()関数でマップしているようです。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/blob/master/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/cores/spresense/wiring_analog.c#L607

個体でのバラつきもありそうですし、実測値からmapして計算するのがリーズナブルな気がします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考に挙げていただいたリンク先の情報にて解決いたしました。

Comment: 解決したようで良かったです